# Is there a way to prevent the back button from overwriting localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I have a web page that when a user clicks a link, it updates local storage. If you press back though the local storage still shows the old value, if you press an additional link it will update the local storage again based off the old already updated local storage value (so really you have two values being displayed).

Is there a way to prevent this and force the back button to still include the updated local storage value?

The following is called on each page:

```
function increaseExternalTime(num) {
  let externalTime = parseInt(seshionStorage.externalTime);
  seshionStorage.externalTime = externalTime + num;
}

export { increaseExternalTime };
```

Comment: Although localStorage is not allowed in snippet but we need to see your code in order to debug it

Comment: Did you try to check if value exists not to update? Share code to help you more.

Comment: Added my code, session was changed to "seshion" to avoid any problems I hope. On a new screen session storage updates. If someone hits the back button (in the browser itself) then it reverts.